# Check if my current branch on local fork exists on remote upstream

Tags: bash, git

`git branch -a | egrep 'remotes/upstream/master'` tells me if master branch exists on upstream or not. That is good.

Lets say my current branch is named as `my_branch` which is the output of  `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.

**Question**
In a bash script, how can I get the output of `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` into a variable and check if that branch exists on upstream or not? I tried the following but it does not work?

```
#!/bin/bash

git checkout master
export MY_BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
git branch -a | egrep 'remotes/upstream/${MY_BRANCH}$'

# Above last command should output "remotes/upstream/master" but it doesn't like it does for "git branch -a | egrep 'remotes/origin/master'"?
```

**PS:**
Should I have to do `git fetch --all` for this to work correctly synced with upstream?

Comment: I updated tags as this is in many ways more a bash question than a Git question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own answer works.  There are a number of shortcuts you can use, but before we visit them, let's start with this:

> Should I have to do `git fetch --all` for this to work correctly synced with upstream?

Given that you're querying your own Git about what it *remembers* about the remote you're calling `upstream`, it is a good idea to run `git fetch upstream`.  Using `git fetch --all` is not a bad idea, and you can use that instead if you'd like to fetch from *both* `origin` *and* `upstream`, so as to update all your `origin/*` and `upstream/*` names.  Given that you're only querying one of the `upstream/*` names, though, all you *need* is an update on those.  Indeed, you could run `git fetch upstream $MY_BRANCH` here, although now we're really getting into hair-splitting.<sup>1</sup>

Now, as to the shortcuts: `git rev-parse` does everything you need.  You don't need `git branch -a` and `grep`.  (You definitely don't need `egrep`: `grep` was originally very simple, then got complicated-up into `grep`, `fgrep`, and `egrep`.  It's been re-simplified in most modern systems, so that when you do need grep, you can just run `grep`, with whatever interface flags you like for the desired behavior.  The program will pick the right algorithm, and run fast on its own.)

- `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`: this prints the current branch name, if there is a current branch name.  If there is *no* current branch name, this prints `HEAD`.  That's almost certainly what you want.<sup>3</sup>
- `git rev-parse refs/remotes/upstream/$MY_BRANCH`: this prints the hash ID corresponding to the name `refs/remotes/upstream/$MY_BRANCH`.  If there is no such name, it prints an error message (see below).

The `refs/` in front of `remotes/upstream/$MY_BRANCH` is simply the way we use the full, un-ambiguous name in Git.  Git normally strips off `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, `refs/remotes/`, or `refs/` from *ref names*, all of which start with `refs/`.  This leaves us with `master` as a branch name, `v1.2` as a tag name, and either `origin/master` or `remotes/origin/master` as a remote-tracking name.

As you've seen, `git branch -a` *doesn't* take off the `remotes/` part from `refs/remotes/origin/master` or `refs/remotes/upstream/master`.  However, if you were to use `git branch -r`, it *would* take the `remotes/` part off, leaving you with, e.g., `origin/master` and `upstream/master`.  There is no obvious reason that `git branch` behaves this way; it just does.  By using `git rev-parse` instead, you avoid having to deal with this particular inconsistency.

---

<sup>1</sup>Presumably, the point of splitting hairs here is to make this go as fast / efficiently as possible.  A `git fetch --all` has your Git call up *each* remote, one at a time,<sup>2</sup> and fetch everything from each.  So this will take as long as it takes to work its way all the way through every remote, one at a time.  Meanwhile, a `git fetch upstream` calls up just the one remote (`upstream`) and then fetches everything there is at the one upstream.  A `git fetch upstream $MY_BRANCH` calls up just the one remote and then asks it only for new commits and such on the one *branch*.

Let's compare the three:

- `--all` dials up every "phone number".  There's a certain amount of slack time in looking up the "phone number" (Internet address) and making the "call" to the server there.  So this could take a few extra seconds.  But once done, everything is updated and you don't have to run `git fetch` until things could have changed: depending on how busy these servers are, anywhere from days, to seconds.
- Using one remote dials one "phone number", then gets all new commits from all branches and updates all the `origin/*` or `upstream/*` or whatever names.  This takes a little longer—sometimes milliseconds, sometimes seconds—than updating just one.  But once done, you'll need to repeat it for any other branch.
- Using one remote and one branch name might gain you a few milliseconds, or as much as a few seconds.  This is usually much smaller than the gain from avoiding `--all`.  How much difference does it make for *your particular cases?*  You'll have to measure.

That last one is really the bottom line, as it were.  Measure, measure, measure.  Or, write something convenient to write, and if it works well enough, stop. :-)

<sup>2</sup>A future Git might be able to call them up in parallel to take advantage of multiple CPUs and so on.  This could change the calculus a bit, or even a lot.

<sup>3</sup>There are several corner cases to consider, as we'll see in the "errors" section below.

---

#### Error messages and corner cases

While `git rev-parse` is great for things that *do* work, there are things that *don't* work.  For instance, here is what happens if I try to `rev-parse` a name that *doesn't* exist:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch
refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The output here is a bit messy:

- The *standard output* from `rev-parse` is just `refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch`.  That is, I gave `rev-parse` a name that does not parse, so it gave that name right back to me.
- The *stderr output* from `rev-parse` has the `fatal: ...`, `Use '--' ...`, and final line.

If all works, we get this:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master
225365fb5195e804274ab569ac3cc4919451dc7f
```

As before, you might want to save this in a variable:

```
$ result=`git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master`
$
```

The shell (sh or bash here) collects the standard output and assigns that to the variable (`$result` here); the standard *error* output goes through to the terminal:

```
$ result=`git rev-parse refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch`
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Note that this time, since the standard output went into `$result`, we did not see `refs/remotes/upstream/foobranch` echoed.

The backquote construct:

```
var=`cmd`
```

is usually better expressed as:

```
var=$(cmd)
```

if for no other reason than parentheses nest.  That is:

```
var=`cmd1 `cmd2` -- `cmd3``
```

might be an attempt to run `cmd1` with the output from `cmd2` and `cmd3` as arguments.  *This does not work*, but:

```
var=$(cmd1 $(cmd2) -- $(cmd3))
```

*does* work.  So we should do that.

We can get or check the *status* of the `$(...)` command:

```
var=$(cmd) || {
    echo "unable to run the given command"
    exit 1
}
```

for instance.  So with `git rev-parse`, if the upstream doesn't exist, we might want:

```
result=$(git rev-parse refs/remotes/upstream/$MY_BRANCH) || exit
```

which will quit the script if `git rev-parse` fails.  The `rev-parse` will still print an error message to stderr.  To suppress that, we have:

```
--quiet --verify
```

as options to `rev-parse`, or we can redirect stderr to `/dev/null`; this part is your choice.

Finally, there are some corner cases to consider with `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD`:

- You can be on a *detached HEAD*.  In this case, as already noted, `git rev-parse` just prints `HEAD`.  If that's what you'd like, go with that.
- You can be in a completely empty repository, or on an *unborn branch* created with `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan`.  In this case, `git rev-parse` produces an error message, and no output.  You should check for this.

Optionally, you can use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.  This has different behavior: it produces the name of the branch if you are on a branch, *including* in the special case of an empty repository or orphan/unborn branch.  But, when in detached-HEAD mode, it produces an error message.

So, in the end, the shortened script is:

```sh
MY_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) || exit
hash=$(git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/remotes/upstream/$MY_BRANCH) || {
    echo "upstream/$MY_BRANCH does not exist"
    exit 1
}
# do whatever you like with upstream/$MY_BRANCH here
```

If you want the hash ID corresponding to `upstream/$MY_BRANCH`, it is in `$hash` now.

Note that there's no point in *exporting* `MY_BRANCH` unless you want to access it from other programs that read an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that I needed to remove the single quotes and it works after that

```
git branch -a | egrep remotes/upstream/$MY_BRANCH
```

Following also works in a one liner:

```
git branch -a | egrep remotes/upstream/`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```